# Grouping a Group with Accumulator

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I want to segment time-series data using separate interval sets. For example, one set has smaller periodic intervals, and one set has larger aperiodic intervals. The interval sets are likely unaligned, such that one from one set may bisect one from the other. In this case the aggregate over the bisected, second interval should resume with the previous value as initial, i.e. an accumulator. The sets are nested in that the carry only occurs between the "inner" set.

For example, *sum*:

```
[.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,., .,.,.,.,.,.][.,.,.,.,.,.,....
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9][1,2,3,4,5,6 ,7,8,9]
[[45],             [21]        ],[[45],      ....
                    |_value carries_|
```

I want to say I should iterate over the dataframe with a for-loop, but...

---

Specifics:

Both intervals sets are series of datetime64 dtype representing boundary or cut points which can be closed either to the left or right. The aperiodic interval set is generated manually, but the periodic set is driven by the time-series data:

```
a = pd.read_csv...
o = pd.offsets.Week(weekday=1)
p = pd.date_range(o.rollback(d.index[0]), o.rollforward(d.index[-1]), freq=o)
```

But it is easy enough to convert both to interval indices, if that helps:

```
p = pd.interval_range(v1.rollback(d.index[0]), v1.rollforward(d.index[-1]), freq=o)
a = pd.IntervalIndex(pd.arrays.IntervalArray.from_breaks(a))
```